# Linux vscode compile all

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

Im using vscode, and in my .vscode folder I have the following Tasks.json:

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

If I try to run the buld task with the "Run" button, I get the error:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g    
     '/some/path/*.cpp' -o /some/path/main

cc1plus: fatal error: /some/path/*.cpp: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.
Build finished with error(s).
```

If I run the command manually, without the quotation marks, it succeeds:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /some/path/*.cpp -o /some/path/main
```

What can I do? Is there some way I can set the args without the quotation marks?

Thanks in advance! I spent a week searching similar problens, but failed to find one with the same issue.

Comment: You can change `"type": "cppbuild"` to `"type": "shell"`, and then a oneliner command without `args`: `"command": "g++ ${fileDirname}/*.cpp -g ....."` (maybe the latter isn't necessary, you need to check). I'm unsure what `"type": "cppbuild",` is doing, but probably nothing too useful.

Comment: Another issue with your tasks.json file is that the name of the program you are building is `${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}`. This name depends on whatever file you happen to be looking at when you start a build. That seems unsatisfactory to me.

Comment: Official [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) recommends `"type": "shell"`

Comment: If I change "cppbuild" to "shell", It doesnt appear on the launch button

Comment: Thanks who tried to help me, and thanks very much whoever closed the unanswered question

Comment: It got marked a duplicate, so you just have to click through to what looks like exactly what you want. Did you try searching before asking? My advice is to learn cmake once you move on to multi-file builds. It's a lot more dependable than this.

Comment: The problem is the developers changed this functionality and broke it. They promise to fix it in 1.19.5 which they expect to be released later in the week.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I've still never liked this approach to multi-file builds in VS Code. I think the proper advice is still to learn a build system.

Comment: If its broken, I'll learn how to use cmake than. Pity that it is broken! Thanks